# Harry Potter characters with alliterative names?

Tags: harry-potter, names

Lots and lots of characters in the *Harry Potter* books have alliterative names (Severus Snape, Peter Pettigrew, Godric Gryffindor, Stan Shunpike, to name but a few).

**Is there a complete list of such characters?**

OK, this is a list question, but it has a finite scope: I want a list of all characters **in the 10 books - the main series, *Fantastic Beasts*, *Quidditch Through the Ages*, and *Tales of Beedle*** (not counting films, fanfics, or whatever else is out there) - whose **first and last names begin with the same letter** (to make clear what definition of 'alliterative' I'm using).

Comment: Yes there is such a list. It's about 3 inches that way ↓

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## A complete list (from everything excluding films, fanfics, and the like) would be:

**Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone**
[Dudley Dursley](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/dursley-family/dudley-dursley/)
[Minerva McGonagall](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/mcgonagall-family/minerva-mcgonagall/)
[Poppy Pomfrey](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/poppy-pomfrey/) (full name in book 3)
[Piers Polkiss](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/piers-polkiss/)
[Marlene McKinnon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/marlene-mckinnon/) (full name in Book 5)
[Bathilda Bagshot](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/bathilda-bagshot/)
[Vindictus Viridian](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/vindictus-viridian/)
[Quirinus Quirrell](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/quirinus-quirrell/) (full name from pottermore)
[Dedalus Diggle](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/dedalus-diggle/)
[William Arthur (Bill) Weasley](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/weasley-family/bill-weasley/) (full name in book 7)
[Gellert Grindelwald](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/gellert-grindelwald/) (full name in book 7)
[Bertie Bott](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/bertie-bott/)
[Gregory Goyle](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/goyle-family/gregory-goyle/)
[Morag MacDougal](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/morag-macdougal/)
[Pansy Parkinson](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/parkinson-family/pansy-parkinson/)
[Padma Patil](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/padma-patil/)
[Parvati Patil](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/parvati-patil/)
[Severus Snape](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/snape-family/severus-snape/)
[Filius Flitwick](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/filius-flitwick/) (Full name in book 6)

**Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets**
[Martin Miggs](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/martin-miggs/)
[Colin Creevey](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/creevey-family/colin-creevey/)
[Gladys Gudgeon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/gladys-gudgeon/)
[Sir Patrick Delaney-Podmore](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/sir-patrick-delaney-podmore/)
[Godric Gryffindor](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/godric-gryffindor/)
[Helga Hufflepuff](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/helga-hufflepuff/)
[Rowena Ravenclaw](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/rowena-ravenclaw/)
[Salazar Slytherin](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/salazar-slytherin/)

**Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban**
[Stan Shunpike](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/stan-shunpike/)
[Florean Fortescue](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/florean-fortescue/)
[Peter Pettigrew](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/peter-pettigrew/)
[Cho Chang](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/cho-chang/)

**Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire**
[Archie Aymslowe](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/archie-aymslowe/)  (full name from Pottermore)
[Broderick Bode](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/broderick-bode/)
[Joey Jenkins](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/joey-jenkins/)
[Bellatrix Black](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/black-family/bellatrix-lestrange/) (full name from book 5)

**Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix**
[Luna Lovegood](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/lovegood-family/luna-lovegood/)
[Inigo Imago](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/inigo-imago/)
[Dilys Derwent](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/dilys-derwent/)
[Willy Widdershins](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/willy-widdershins/)

**Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows**
[Ted Tonks](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/ted-tonks/)
[Wendell Wilkins](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/wendell-wilkins/)
[Arkie Alderton](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/arkie-alderton/)
[Mary MacDonald](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/mary-macdonald/)
[Betty Braithwaite](https://www.www.hp-lexicon.org/character/betty-braithwaite/)

**Quidditch through the Ages**
[Magnus “Dent Head” Macdonald](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/magnus-dent-head-macdonald/)
[Barberus Bragge](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/barberus-bragge/)
[Glynnis Griffiths](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/Glynnis-Griffiths/)
[Meaghan McCormack](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/meaghan-mccormack/)

**Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them**
[Tilly Toke](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/Tilly-Toke/)
[Wilhelm Wigworthy](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/wilhelm-wigworthy/)

**The Tales of Beedle the Bard**
[Beatrix Bloxam](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/beatrix-bloxam/) (first appeared on famous wizard card)

**Daily Prophet Newsletters**
[Willy Wagstaff](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/honest-willy-wagstaff/)
[Phoebus Penrose](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/phoebus-penrose/)
[Galvin Gudgeon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/galvin-gudgeon/)
[Barnabus Blenkinsop](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/barnabus-blenkinsop/)
[Brevis Birch](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/brevis-birch/)
[Hilliard Hobday](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/hobday-family/hilliard-hobday/)
[Elveira Elkins](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/elveira-elkins/)

**Famous Wizard Cards**
[Balfour Blane](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/balfour-blane/)
[Daisy Dodderidge](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/daisy-dodderidge/)
[Archibald Alderton](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/archibald-alderton/)
[Thaddeus Thurkell](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/thaddeus-thurkell/)
[Crispin Cronk](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/crispin-cronk/)
[Blodwyn Bludd](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/Blodwyn-Bludd/)

**old jkrowling.com**
[Tilden Toots](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/tilden-toots/)

**Black Family Tree**
[Belvina Black](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/black-family/belvina-black/)

**Pottermore**
[Perseus Parkinson](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/parkinson-family/perseus-parkinson/)
[Archie Aymslowe](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/archie-aymslowe/)
[Malcolm Mcgonagall](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/mcgonagall-family/malcolm-mcgonagall/)
[Hankerton Humble](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/hankerton-humble/)
[Lars Lundekvam](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/lars-lundekvam/)
[Niko Nenad](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/niko-nenad/)
[Wladyslaw Wolfke](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/wladyslaw-wolfke/)
[Willi Wenzel](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/willi-wenzel/)
[Bruno Bruunhart](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/bruno-bruunhart/)
[Carlos Clodoaldo](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/carlos-clodoaldo/)
[Quintia Qarase](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/quintia-qarase/)
[Alejandra Alonso](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/alejandra-alonso/)
[Bartholomew Barebone](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/bartholomew-barebone/)

## Bonus

**Characters with other alliterations**
[Justin Finch-Fletchley](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/finch-fletchley-family/justin-finch-fletchley/)
[Babbitty Rabbitty](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/babbitty-rabbitty/)
[Lilly Luna Potter](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/potter-family/lily-luna-potter/)
[Egmont Elvert Hobday](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/hobday-family/egmont-elvert-hobday/)
[Hope Howell Lupin](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/lupin-family/hope-howell-lupin/)
[Jean-Baptiste Bloncourt](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/jean-baptiste-bloncourt/)

**Characters with alliterative titles**
[Madam Malkin](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/madam-malkin/)
[Fat Friar](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/the-fat-friar/)
[Nearly-Headless Nick](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/nearly-headless-nick/)
[Bloody Baron](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/the-bloody-baron/)
[Emeric the Evil](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/emeric-the-evil/)
[Uric the Oddball](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/uric-the-oddball/)
[Elfric the Eager](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/elfric-the-eager/)
[Whomping Willow](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/item/whomping-willow/)
[Bandon Banshee](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/bandon-banshee/)
[Moaning Myrtle](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/moaning-myrtle/)
[Wailing Widow](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/wailing-widow/)
[Wagga Wagga Werewolf](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/wagga-wagga-werewolf/)
[Wendelin the Weird](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/wendelin-the-weird/)
[Madam Marsh](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/madam-marsh/)
[Gunhilda of Gorsemoor](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/gunhilda-of-gorsemoor/)
[Mad-Eye Moody](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/alastor-mad-eye-moody/)
[Urg the Unclean](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/urg-the-unclean/)
[Lachlan the Lanky](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/lachlan-the-lanky/)
[Wilfred the Wistful](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/wilfred-the-wistful/)
[Barnabus the Barmy](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/barnabas-the-barmy/)
[Beedle the Bard](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/beedle-the-bard-2/)
[Egbert the Egregious](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/egbert-the-egregious/)
[Dodgy Dirk](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/dodgy-dirk/)
[Fingal the Fearless](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/fingal-the-fearless/)
[Ingolfr the Iambic](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/ingolfr-the-iambic/)
[Eargit the Ugly](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/eargit-the-ugly/)
[Alguff the Awful](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/alguff-the-awful/)
[Ug the Unreliable](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/ug-the-unreliable/)
[Bran the Bloodthirsty](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/bran-the-bloodthirsty/)
[Lisette de Lapin](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/lisette-de-lapin/)
[Hodrod the Horny-Handed](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/hodrod-the-horny-handed/)
[Brodrig the Boss-Eyed](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/brodrig-the-boss-eyed/)
[Ethelred the Ever-Ready](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/ethelred-the-ever-ready/)
[Merwyn the Malicious](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/merwyn-the-malicious/)
[Fulbert the Fearful](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/fulbert-the-fearful/)

Comment: All links are to The Harry Potter Lexicon's [secret new site](https://beta.hp-lexicon.org).

Comment: Martin Miggs might count double, since even his epithet, _the Mad Muggle_, is alliterative. So he could go in the last section as well. Could you explain how Uric the Oddball is alliterative, though?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - My goal with the latter section was to include characters who otherwise wouldn't make the list. (Same reason that Dudley isn't mentioned under all seven books)

Comment: True—but in Martin's case, it's really two different 'names' that just happen to be both alliterative. Just saying you could argue for having him twice. (Also, I edited my last comment while you were typing, I think.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Yeah, but their the same character. Uric the Oddball is alliterative for the same reason that Clark Kent is.

Comment: How so? Uric the Oddball begins with two different letters, pronounced in two different ways? Neither sound nor writing matches (and the question specifies that we're talking only _letters_ here, not sounds—in the most common definition of alliteration, Clark Kent is alliterative, but Stan Shunpike isn't, but that's not relevant here).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Aren't all variables alliterative? Either-way I included it in the clearly marked non-answer extra part of my answer.

Comment: @ibid - I agree with JanusBahsJacquet. Uric seems a stretch too far, as does Eargit the Ugly. They don't even sound similar.

Comment: @Richard - That whole section was for names that I thought a stretch to far

Answer (score 11):

A complete list (from the <s>ten</s> eleven novels) would be

**Archibald (Arkie) Alderton

Bathsheda Babbling

Bathilda Bagshot

Balfour Blane

Beatrix Bloxam

[Bellatrix Black](https://media.hp-lexicon.org/legacy/images/blackfamilytrees/official-final-version.gif)

Blodwyn Bludd

Broderick Bode

Bertie Bott

Barberus Bragge

Cho Chang

Colin Creevy

Crispin Cronk

Dilys Derwent

Dedalus Diggle

[Delphini 'Diggory'](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Delphini) (warning, here be spoilers for Cursed Child)

Daisy Dodderidge

Dudley Dursley

Filius Flitwick

Florean Fortescue

Gregory (Jr and Sr) Goyle

Glynnis Griffiths

Gelert Grindelwald

Godric Gryffindor

Galvin Gudgeon

Gladys Gudgeon

Helga Hufflepuff

Inigo Imago

Joey Jenkins

Luna Lovegood

Magnus Macdonald

Meghan McCormack

Minerva McGonagall

Marlene McKinnon

Morag MacDougal

Pansy Parkinson

Padma Patil

Parvati Patil

Peter Pettigrew

Piers Polkiss

Poppy Pomfrey

Quirinus Quirell

Rowena Ravenclaw

Salazar Slytherin

Severus Snape

Stan Shunpike

Thaddeus Thurkell

Tilly Tokes

Ted Tonks

Tilde Toots

Vindictus Viridian

William Weasley

Willy Widdershins

Wilhelm Wigworthy**

If you would like to know more about any of these characters, they're all found [here](http://magical-menagerie.com/wizardry/full-character-listing/) and [here](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page) along with a brief listing about their achievements in-universe.

Comment: Even though it's nickname, shouldn't Moaning Myrtle make the list?

Comment: @zikato - you'd be hard-pressed to argue that "Moaning" is her first name.

Comment: @Richard - I'm ashamed to admit that I don't recall her first name without looking up. Next question - is JKR an avid fan of Kirby and early Superman?

Comment: @DVK - Inspired by Stan Lee, perhaps?

Comment: @Richard - whichever one of them flooded the Superman universe with alliterations.

Comment: For what it's worth, Ted Tonks' full first name was actually Edward. (Source: [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/nymphadora-tonks))

Comment: Is there any evidence for or against Bill Weasley's name being short for William?

Comment: @studoku - While it's certainly possible that Molly, Fred and Perry aren't actually Margaret, Frederick and Percival, we do know that Ron is Ronald and Ginny is Ginevra, strongly implying a tradition of diminutive names within the family.

Comment: @Richard Moaning Myrtle's first name was the first WoG statement that JKR posted on Twitter IIRC.

Comment: Am I missing something in the comments here? DVK doesn’t recall Moaning Myrtle’s first name, and @ibid says it was the first WoG statement JKR posted on Twitter… but Moaning Myrtle’s first name is surely ***Myrtle***, isn’t it?

Comment: @ibid - He means surname. Myrtle Warren

Comment: FWIW Quirrel's first name only appears in the Trading Card Game and Pottermore.

Comment: @ibid - That may be true, but the character exists within the books. Similarly, Bellatrix is never named as a 'Black' but a canon source confirms that that's what she was...

Comment: @Richard - Bellatrix is a 'Black' in Book 5, Chapter 6: *He pointed to another  small round burn mark between **two names, Bellatrix  and Narcissa. “Andromeda’s sisters are still here**  because they made lovely, respectable pure-blood marriages, but Andromeda married a Muggleborn, Ted Tonks, so —” Sirius mimed blasting the tapestry  with a wand  and laughed sourly. Harry, however, did not laugh; he  was too busy staring at the names to the right of Andromeda’s burn mark. A  double line of gold embroidery linked **Narcissa Black with Lucius Malfoy***.

Comment: @ibid - Well there you go then. It looks like I was right to steal Karen's answer :-)

Comment: @Richard - Blodwyn Bludd, Daisy Dodderidge, and Thaddeus Thurkell can only be found on Famous Wizard Cards. Galvin Gudgeon can only be found in the Daily Prophet Newsletters.

Comment: Well, I updated my answer to include the ten books as well (and I sorted them by book). Maybe @randal'thor will like it better.

Comment: @ibid Definitely worth a +1. I'll have to think about the acceptance :-)

Comment: @ibid - Definitely worthy of the acceptance in my opinion now that you've added in the books.

Comment: @randal'thor - Have you thought any further about acceptance yet?

Comment: @ibid Sure. I was on the fence about transferring the acceptance, but since Richard's answer has more upvotes (and he has *more* than enough rep!), I may as well compensate a bit. Richard: I trust there will be no hard feelings, given your last comment above :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - Nah, it's the better answer, even if vast tranches of it are unsolicited extras.

Comment: @Richard - I find it difficult to answer HP questions without quoting from the more obscure parts of the canon. :)

Comment: Should that not be Delphini 'Diggory'?

Comment: @Adamant - I've amended accordingly and popped a spoiler warning on.

Comment: Considering that my answer only has names of characters from Rowling's works, that will be one name yours has which mine doesn't.

Comment: @ibid - She said it was canon and contributed heavily to the production. Her name is on the poster. That's good enough for me.

Answer (score 7):

Bellatrix Lestrange was originally **Bellatrix Black**, as stated in the [HP Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/bellatrix.html) and seen in the [Black family tree](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/blackfamilytrees/official-final-version.gif) that Sirius shows to Harry.

Comment: Hi Karen, I took the liberty of adding in a couple of sources to your answer, to prevent it from getting downvoted. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: And added to my answer. Cheers. [Yoink!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJh1hmmLLzw)