# Which Marvel characters have alliterative names?

Tags: marvel

Many characters in *Marvel* have alliterative names, such as Peter Parker, J. Jonah Jameson, and Reed Richards.

Is there a complete list of Marvel characters whose first and last names begin with the same letter?

---

<sub>Yes, this is a list question, but it has a limited scope: If you're finding an unreasonable amount of names then we can limit this to just main and secondary characters while excluding random extras like Happy Hogan.</sub>

<sub>Inspired by [Harry Potter characters with alliterative names?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/98752/harry-potter-characters-with-alliterative-names)</sub>

Comment: LOL, just about every character named by Stan Lee.

Comment: Hmm... You ask for alliterations (question title) but at the same time ask for names that start with the same letter (question content). Which is it? From Thunderforge's answer, Sebastian Shaw has names that start with the same letters but it's not an alliteration... (except if pronounced by Leonard Nimoy ;-)

Comment: I don't think the length limit will allow answering this in a single post.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Captain America

- Bucky Barnes

### Captain Britain

- Betsy Braddock
- Brian Braddock

### Daredevil

- Matt Murdoch (Daredevil)
- Parnival Plunder (Plunderer)

### Dr. Strange

- Steven Strange (Dr. Strange)
- Fin Fang Foom

### Fantastic Four

- Reed Richards (Mr. Fantastic)
- Sue Storm (Invisible Woman, before marriage)
- Silver Surfer
- Wyatt Wingfoot (star athlete and friend to Johnny Storm)
- Victor Von Doom (Doctor Doom)
- Peter Petruski (Paste-Pot Pete)

### Hulk

- Bruce Banner (Hulk)
- Betty Banner (Bruce's one-time wife)
- Brian Banner (Bruce's father)
- Samuel Sterns (Leader)

### Iron Man

- Happy Hogan (assistant)
- Pepper Potts (assistant)

### Spider-Man

- Peter Parker (Spider-Man)
- Miles Morales (Ultimate Spider-Man)
- Peter Porker (Spider-Ham)

  **Supporting Cast**

  - J. Jonah Jameson Jr. (newspaper editor)
  - Also, his father, JJJ Sr., and his son, JJJ III
  - Betty Brant (Jameson's assistant)
  - Carlie Cooper (girlfriend of Peter)
  - Glory Grant (neighbor of Peter)
  - Max Modell (tech specialist for Peter)
  - Robbie Robertson (Daily Bugle editor)
  - Randy Robertson (classmate of Peter, son of Robbie)

  **Villains**

  - Green Goblin
  - Dr. Otto Octavius (Doctor Octopus)
  - Cletus Cassidy (Carnage)
  - Curt Connors (Lizard)
  - Dr. Michael Morbius (Morbius the Living Vampire)
  - Silver Sablinova (Silver Sable)
  - Lonnie Lincoln (Tombstone)
  - Donna Diego (Scream)
  - Frederick Foswell (Big Man)
  - Moses Magnum

### Thor

- Loki Laufeyson (brother of Thor)
- Balder the Brave (companion of Thor)
- Beta Ray Bill (rival to Thor)

### X-Men

- Moira MacTaggert (scientist)
- Scott Summers (Cyclops)
- Sebastian Shaw (supervillain)
- Shinobi Shaw (supervillain, son of Sebastian)
- Warren Worthington III (Angel)

  **X-Men 2099**

  - Xi'an Chi Xan (Desert Ghost/Controller X)

    - Note that the "X" is pronounced as "Sh"
  - Henri Huang (Meanstreak)

### Other

- Jessica Jones
- Kamala Khan (Ms. Marvel)
- Richard Rider (Nova)
- Wade Winston Wilson (Deadpool)
- Greer Grant (Tigra)
- Blackagar Boltagon (Black Bolt)
- Val Ventura (Flatman)
- Rocket Raccoon (Guardian of the Galaxy)
- Dum Dum Duggan (one of the Howling Commandos)
- Robert Reynlods (Sentinel)
- Lindy Lee (maiden name of Robert Reynolds' wife)
- Carl "Crusher" Creel (The Absorbing Man)
- Mary MacPherran (Titania)
- Adam Austin (Masked Man)
- Robbie Reyes (Ghost Rider)
- Big Bertha
- Dennis Dunphy (Demolition Man)
- Barney Barton (older brother of Clint Barton, Hawkeye)
- Millie the Model (humor comic published by Marvel)

### And a lot more…

I barely scratched the surface with this, as there are *many* more characters with alliterative names. Still, the major ones, a number of secondary characters, and a few "never heard of 'ems" are in there. If anybody sees any glaring omissions, feel free to edit them in.

### Why so many?

In a [2006 Q&A](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=8550), Stan Lee explained why there are so many alliterative names:

> "It would be hard for you to believe this, because I seem so perfect: I have the worst memory in the world," Stan said. "So I finally figured out, if I could give somebody a name, where the last name and the first name begin with the same letter, like Peter Parker, Bruce Banner, Matt Murdock, then if I could remember one name, it gave me a clue what the other one was, I knew it would begin with the same letter."

Comment: +1 here's [this](http://community.comicbookresources.com/showthread.php?1197-List-as-Many-Marvel-Characters-with-Alliterative-Names-as-You-Can) if it helps. Enjoy your well-earned rep (and don't forget to upvote the question) :)

Comment: When asked about these names Stan Lee said : "It would be hard for you to believe this, because I seem so perfect: I have the worst memory in the world," Stan said. "So I finally figured out, if I could give somebody a name, where the last name and the first name begin with the same letter, like Peter Parker, Bruce Banner, Matt Murdock, then if I could remember one name, it gave me a clue what the other one was, I knew it would begin with the same letter." . So he was just cheating to make them easy to remember :D

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ Adding to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: "•Loki Laufeyson (brother of Thor)" - well, "he's adopted".

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ Which still didn't prevent him from getting Spider-Man's real name wrong in Amazing Spider-Man #1!

Comment: @PatrickWynne yeah and there is one about Hulk too. You see, Hulk's real name is "Robert Bruce Banner" because Stan got it wrong in an issue and changed his name afterwards instead of fixing that mistake.

Comment: Not sure if Doctor Doom qualifies, "von" is read as "fon" according to German pronunciation rules.

Comment: @Malcolm Fair, although he was a character created by an American comic book company for American audiences, who presumably would be pronouncing it as "vahn".

Comment: Carnage's real name is [Cletus Kasady](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Cletus_Kasady_(Earth-616)), not Cletus Cassidy. Also. Robbie Robertson's real name is [Joe Robertson](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Joseph_Robertson_(Earth-616)). 'Robbie' is just a nickname, a shortened version of his surname.

Comment: @Thunderforge Agents of SHIELD shoutout with Melinda May.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a new list of more than 1400 alliterative characters from Marvel and DC
https://github.com/mroughan/AlephZeroHeroesData/blob/master/Comics/alli_data3_names.csv

Description of the source of the list is here:
https://aleph-zero-heroes.netlify.com/posts/alliteration/

Short list of additional characters:

Heroes

- Amara Aquilla (Magma, New Mutants)
- Celeste Cuckoo (Phoenix, Stepford Cuckoos)
- Quintavius Quirinius Quire (Kid Omega, WC Avengers, X-men)
- Michiko "Mickey" Musashi (Turbo, Torpedo Sue, Avengers)
- Barnell Bohusk (Beak, new X-men)
- Alexander Aaron (Phobos, son of Ares)
- Yo Yo Rodriguez (Slingshot)
- Kara Killgrave (Killgrave's daughter)
- Red Raven (Liberty Legion)
- Andromeda Attumasen (Atlantians)
- Daniel Drumm (Master of Mystic Arts, New York Sanctum, pre-Dr Strange)

Howling Commandos

- "Rebel" Robert Ralston
- Percival Pinkerton
- Samuel Sawyer

Spiderverse

- Marla Madison (marries J.Jonah Jameson)
- Mamie Muggins (Peter Parker's landlady)
- Sha Shan Nguyen (Sister Sun, Flash Thompson’s girlfriend)

Villains and "it's complicated"

- Charlie Cluster-7 (Fantomex)
- Matthew Masters (the Black Rider)
- Sinthea "Sin" Shmidt (Red Skull's daughter)
- Zheng Zu (Fu Manchu)
- Samuel Smithers (Plantman)
- Boris Bullski (Titanium Man, early rival of Vanko and Stark)
- Samuel Saxon (Machinesmith, ally of the Tinkerer)
- Maxwell Markham (Grizzly)
- Maki Matsumoto (Lady Bullseye, the Hand)
- Steel Serpent (Davos, enemy of Iron Fist)
- Susan Scarbo (Mother Night, ally of Red Skull)
- Bella Donna Boudreaux (Belladonna, Gambit's ex-wife)

Comment: Don't forget our best boy - Billy Batson! (DC) Doesn't seem like he is on your lists so far

Comment: @Will because the question is about Marvel characters

Comment: @OrangeDog . True, but I think the first list was supposed to have both dc and marvel. Not super important for this question though!

Comment: The problem with "Billy" Batson is he is listed as William Batson in the original data. The code isn't quite clever enough to extrapolate. There's probably a few other similar ones missing.

Answer (score 0):

JUST from Spider-man's rogues' gallery and excluding ones that have already been listed:

- Sinister Six
- Sinister Syndicate
- Emissaries of Evil
- Savage Six
- Man Mountain Marko - Michael Marko
- Hammerhead
- Man-Wolf - John Jameson
- Grizzle - Maxwell Markham
- Will o' the Wisp - Jackson Arvad
- Styx and Stone
- Grey Goblin
- Foreigner - Kris Keating
- White Rabbit - Dr. Lorina Dodson
- Tombstone -   Lonnie Thompson Lincoln
- Spidercide - Freakface
- Molten Man - Mark Raxton
- Rocket Racer - Robert Farrell
- Silver Sable - Silver Sablinova
- Brix & Bora

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. The question did seem to be asking about characters' real "first and last names" though, not their superhero/supervillain names, like "Molten Man" and "Rocket Racer". You also included some team names here, like "Sinister Six" and "Sinister Syndicate", which seem even further away from what the question was asking for. And why are "Hammerhead" and "White Rabbit / Dr. Lorina Dodson" on the list? "Hammerhead" is not only a supervillain name, but a _single_ name. And are you counting the title "Dr." as a name?

Comment: @LogicDictates if the reason given at the bottom of the accepted answer is true, (alliteration as memory aid) showing it expands to team names and hero names reinforces the point. Dr. Dodson is odd, but perhaps the character rarely used their given name?

Comment: @Jontia - Stan's reason for using alliterative names doesn't alter the nature of the question in my view. Also, there are further issues with this answer. John Jameson, Silver Sablinova, and Lonnie Lincoln were all mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120220/122024), and 'Freakface' is just a nickname Ben Reilly gave to Spidercide, not his real name (he was a clone of Peter Parker, and never had a civilian name of his own). Plus, 'Freakface', like Hammerhead', is one name, not two.