# Which DC characters have alliterative names?

Tags: dc

Many characters in *DC* have alliterative names, such as Billy Batson, Lex Luthor. and Wally West.

Is there a complete list of DC characters whose first and last names begin with the same letter?

---

<sub>Yes, this is a list question, but it has a limited scope: If you're finding an unreasonable amount of names then we can limit this to just main and secondary characters while excluding random extras like Lucy Lane.</sub>

<sub><strike>Inspired by</strike> Shamelessly stolen from [Which Marvel characters have alliterative names?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120217/which-marvel-characters-have-alliterative-names)</sub>

Comment: Would Clark Kent count? Both names have a Hard 'K' sound.  Does it have to be an alter ego? Otherwise Wonder Woman and Martian Manhunter would count as well.

Comment: It is not a question of limited scope, because DC is still in business, and for all we know they are going to keep on inventing new characters till the end of time. And every time they create a new alliterative character the answers will have to be updated.

Comment: @user14111 - It's just a shameless ripoff of RedCaio's Marvel question. Blame him.

Comment: @user14111 actually, I blame Rand for his [Harry Potter question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/98752/harry-potter-characters-with-alliterative-names). :) (kidding)

Comment: Is this a comic book phenomena or is it a generational thing?   I watched a movie about heroes from the Norwegian resistance during WWII and noticed that there were alitterative names on these historic figures (real names not cover names) of a core membership of twelve men as many as five had Allitterative names.  
Can it be relevant that many DC heroes started in the forties and that Stan Lee also was of the same generation?  Was alliterative names a more common thing in the past?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given DC's long history, there's no feasable way to compile a complete list of all the charatcers with alliterative names. Taken largely from this [List of human superheroes in DC Comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_superheroes_in_DC_Comics) and many helpful comments from Wad Cheber, I have put together what can serve as a decent starting point for DC characters with alliterative names.

**Characters:**

- Adrian Alexander Veidt (Ozymandias)
- Batman Beyond (Batman)
- Beast Boy (Teen Titans)
- Bernhard "Buddy" Baker (Animal Man)
- Bibbo Bukowski (Superman)
- Billy Batson (Captain Marvel)
- Blue Beetle
- Calvin "Cave" Carson
- Captain Cold (Flash)
- Captain Comet
- Cassandra Cain (Batgirl)
- Clark Kent (Superman)
- Dan the Dyna-Mite (Daniel Dunbar)
- Daniel Dreiberg (Nite Owl)
- Deborah Darnell AKA Star Sapphire (Green Lantern)
- Dinah Drake Lance (Black Canary)
- Doiby Dickles (Green Lantern)
- Felix Faust AKA Dekan Drache
- Francis Flashman AKA Funky Flashman
- Frederick Freeman (New Earth / Captain Marvel Jr.)
- Gorilla Grodd (Flash)
- Guy Gardner (Green Lantern)
- Hank Hall (Hawk)
- James Jacob "Jim" Harper (Guardian)
- Joseph William Wilson (Jericho)
- Karate Kid (Val Armorr - Legion of Super-Heroes)
- James Jesse AKA Trickster (Green Arrow)
- J'onn J'onzz (Martian Manhunter)
- Joker Junior (Tim Drake)
- Lana Lang (Superman)
- Lex Luthor (Superman)
- Linda Lee (Supergirl)
- Liz Lane (Watchmen)
- Lois Lane (Superman)
- Lori Lemaris (Superman)
- Mary Marvel (Mary Willow Batson)
- Mark Mandrill AKA Matter Master (Hawkman)
- Más y Menos (Teen Titans)
- Max Mercury AKA Whip Whirlwind (Freedom Fighters)
- Mirror Master (Flash)
- Miss Martian (M'gann M'orzz/Megan Morse, also Star-Spangled Kid)
- Mister Mxyzptlk
- Moloch The Mystic (Watchmen)
- Preston Payne (Batman)
- Rachel Roth (Raven)
- Red Robin (Robin)
- Robbie Reed (Dial H for Hero)
- Rocket Red (Justice League / Rocket Red Brigade)
- Rodney Rabbit AKA Captain Carrot (New Teen Titans)
- Ronald "Ronnie" Raymond (Firestorm)
- Sargent "Sarge" Steel
- Shiera Sanders Hall (Hawkgirl)
- Silk Spectre (Sally Jupiter / Laurie Juspeczyk)
- Silver St. Cloud (Batman)
- Tex Thompson (Mr. America)
- Vicky Vale (Batman)
- Wally West (Kid Flash)
- William "Bill" Benjamin Brady (Watchmen)
- Wonder Woman (Princess Diana of Themyscira)
- Zatanna Zatara (Hawkman)

**Group names:**

- Freedom Fighters
- Secret Society of Super Villains
- Secret Six
- Seven Soldiers of Victory (AKA Law's Legionnaires)
- Suicide Squad
- Teen Titans
- The Terrific Trio
- Hero Hotline

---

Plus loads and loads of random people from the [List of DC Comics characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DC_Comics_characters):

- Aa (Green Lantern)
- Abdul the Arab (Quality Comics)
- Ace Archer (The Green Arrows Of The World - Japan)
- Bowman of Britain (The Green Arrows Of The World - United Kingdom)
- Bowman of the Bush (The Green Arrows Of The World - Africa)
- Ace Atchinson (Young Justice)
- Sue Storm (Ace Storm - Challengers of the Fantastic)
- Agent Arrhnyr (Action Comics 534)
- Agent Axis (Boy Commandos / World's Finest Team)
- Aisha al-Fadhil (The Losers)
- Alan Armstrong (Spy Smasher)
- Albart of Ancinor (Atlantis Chronicles)
- Albert the Artist (Action Comics 428)
- Ana Ala (Ale - Superman: The Man of Steel, #127)

...

---

From [Why Are There So Many Double Initials in Comic Books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9375/why-are-there-so-many-double-initials-in-comic-books?lq=1)

> [What is the L. L. connection for Superman?](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/comics/comics.php?topic=comics-sfaq#Q33)
>
> A remarkably large number of characters in the comics have the initials L. L. Most notable are Lex Luthor, Lois Lane, Lana Lang, and Lori Lemaris. A rumor says that these names were chosen because Joe Shuster's first girlfriend had the initials L. L.

Comment: Did you seriously comb through that entire list? I had tried using it and gave up.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aj9Bx.png

Comment: http://community.comicbookresources.com/showthread.php?1195-List-as-Many-DC-Characters-with-Alliterative-Names-as-You-Can

Comment: @WadCheber thanks. I already had martian manhunter, I was just missing the "martian" part. My first time answering one of these list questions. (well beside the vocals in SW music one). I'll think twice before tackling one of these again. lol

Comment: @ibid At fist I was combing thru the larger list of all DC characters but realized it'd take a day for each letter of the alphabet, so I switched to the list of DC heroes since it was shorter.

Comment: Preston Payne - the third Clayface (Batman)

Comment: Secret Society of Super Villains https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Society_of_Super_Villains

Comment: Matter Master,
Felix Faust,
Trickster (James Jesse)

Comment: Star Sapphire (Deborah Darnell), Funky Flashman, Gorilla Grodd, Captain Cold, 
Captain Comet, Mirror Master

Comment: @WadCheber that first link of yours was what I used to write the question (after giving up with Wikipedia).

Comment: Secret Six (group)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Six_(comics)

Comment: (William) "Bill" Benjamin Brady - Dollar Bill (One of the Minutemen in Watchmen)

Comment: Moloch The Mystic (Watchmen)

Comment: Liz Lane/Twilight Woman (Watchmen)

Comment: Linda Lee/Supergirl, Bibbo Bukowski (Superman), Silver St. Cloud (Batman), Robbie Reed (Dial H for Hero), Billy Batson (Captain Marvel), Doiby Dickles (golden age Green Lantern's sidekick), Calvin "Cave" Carson, Max Mercury/Whip Whirlwind, Sargent "Sarge" Steel, Tex Thompson, aka "Mr. America" and "Americommando"...

Comment: Zatanna Zatara, Rodney Rabbit/Captain Carrot.

Comment: If "Mister Mxyzptlk" counts as an alliterative character name, they there's also [Mr. Mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Mind_and_the_Monster_Society_of_Evil), and Mr. (Sterling) Morris (Billy Batson's boss at station WHIZ), and no doubt many others.

Answer (score 2):

Too many to count, let alone name in an answer.  To highlight my point, I will restrict myself to just SOME entities with alliterative names that appear in Batman media (and **only** those not mentioned in the excellent previous answer at the time I wrote this answer).

- Arkham Asylum (place)
- Bag O'Bones
- Bat Bane
- Beetles Branagan
- Birthday Boy
- Bizarro-Batman
- Black Bat/Cassandra Cain
- Black and White Bandit
- Boston Brand/Deadman
- "Brains" Beldon
- Cameron van Cleer/Killer Moth
- Captain Calamity
- Carl Kruger
- Carrie Kelley/Robin
- Charise Carnes/Knightfall
- Charlie Caligula
- Chu Chin Li
- Clock King (I and II)
- Condiment King
- Cyber Cat/Christina Chiles
- Mayor Daniel Danforth Dickerson III
- Doctor Daark
- Doctor Death
- Doctor Double X
- Double Dare (team)
- Dr. Dedalus
- Duela Dent (Joker's Daughter)
- Eivol Ekdal
- False Face
- False Face Society (team)
- Fearsome Foot-Fighters (team)
- Film Freak
- Gentleman Ghost
- Gentleman Jim Jansen
- Getaway Genius/Roy Reynolds
- Gorilla Gang (team)
- Jezebel Jet
- Jim Jones
- Kate Kane/Batwoman
- Killer Croc
- King Cobra
- King Kraken
- King of Cats/Karl Kyle
- Mad Monk
- Mallory Moxon
- Matches Malone
- Mirror Master
- Monarch of Menace
- Monster Men (team)
- Mousery Mager
- Mr. Mosaic
- Music Meister
- Pearly Prince
- Penny Plunderer (the guy who made the giant penny in the Batcave)
- Peter Pan Killer
- Commissioner Peter Pauling
- Preston Payne (Clayface III)
- Professor Pyg
- Rory Regan/Ragman
- Roxy Rocket
- Ruby Ryder
- Savage Skull
- Silken Spider
- Silver St. Cloud
- Sterling Silversmith
- Terrible Trio (team)
- The Trigger Twins (team)
- Warren White/Great White Shark
- Zatanna Zatara

*Note:  Red Caio has my permission to use anything he likes from my answer to supplement his own;  I am not trying to supplant his answer, I am merely trying to illustrate how impossible it would be to list every alliterative name in DC history.*

Comment: Is it worse than Marvel?

Comment: @ibid - Probably not.  But there probably isn't a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new list of more than 1400 alliterative characters from Marvel and DC
https://github.com/mroughan/AlephZeroHeroesData/blob/master/Comics/alli_data3_names.csv

Description of the source of the list is here:
https://aleph-zero-heroes.netlify.com/posts/alliteration/

Turns out DC uses alliterative names more than Marvel, but not much.

Here's some examples from the list (trying to avoid those mentioned earlier)

- Mari McCabe (Vixen)
- Big Barda (Barda Free)
- Abigail Arcane Holland (wife of Abigail Arcane Cable Holland)
- Hector Hall (Silver Scarab and Doctor Fate)
- Eve Eden (Nightshade)
- Thomas Tresser (Nemesis)
- Hans von Hammer (Enemy Ace)
- Terrence Thirteen (Dr Thirteen)
- Traci Thirteen (Girl 13)
- Hannibal Hawkes (Nighthawk)
- Valentina Vostok (Negative Woman, White Queen)
- Hop Harrigan (Guardian Angel, Black Lamp)
- Sonia Sato (Judomaster)
- Mark Merlin (nephew of "The Mighty Merlin")
- Sister Sunlight
- Zachary Zatara

Superman, L.L.

- Lee St. Lawrence (saved by Superboy)
- Light Lass (Lightning Lass, Legion of Super-Heroes)
- Lightning Lad (Legion of Super-Heroes)
- Lightning Lord (Legion of Super-Villains)
- Louise Lincoln (Killer Frost II)

Supporting Characters:

- Wolfgang "Woozy" Winks (sidekick of Plastic Man)
- Sapphire Stagg (daughter of Simon Stagg and love interest of Metamorpho)
- Cameron Chase
- Catherine Cobert (United Nations liaison with Justice League Europe)

Villains and "it's complicated"

- Michael Miller (Human Flame)
- Weather Witch
- Mark Mardon (Weather Wizard)
- Giovanni Giuseppe (James Jesse, Trickster)
- Granny Goodness
- Simon Stagg
- Henry Henshaw (Cyborg Superman)
- Lord of Limbo
- Samuel Scudder (Mirror Master)
- Scandal Savage (daughter Vandal Savage)
- Clifford Carmichael (The Thinker)
- Death-Doll (originally Liberty-Lass)
- Doc Dread
- Devil Dog
- Dark Druid
- Anton Arcane
- Wanda Wayland (Ten of Spades)
- Appa Ali Apsa
- Zilius Zox

Comment: The link is helpful and certainly answers the question and it would probably be too long to add all the names into the post but you should consider including most of the DC main characters with alliterative names into your post in case the link does.